# "Unknown subcircuit" in LTSpiceXVII

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I'm attempting to simulate a circuit that is intended to take a 5V/GND input and make split +/- 2.5V rails with a virtual ground.

When I try to simulate, LTSpice complains about "unknown subcircuit" as shown in the screenshot.  I have placed red arrows to indicate the wires that are mentioned in the error dialog.

[image]

What does this error mean and how may I fix it?

Note: I'm using sine wave voltage and current sources to simulate noisy rails and loads.

Comment: you should insert ".inc opamp.sub" in ".op", press 's' key to access ".op".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I said in my comment, LTSpice can't find the sub-circuit for the device U1. If you look at the text in the box, it says XU1, which is the ref-des given to the op-amp, the rest of text mentions the nets going in to said op-amp.

Comment: I think it was the wording of the message that threw me.  I thought I had somehow created a "subcircuit" (whatever that is) in my schematic.  I went back to the component selection dialog and chose an opamp with a model attached to it.  I guess "subcircuit" is synonymous with "model" in LTSpice.   Thanks.

Comment: If you open the model file in a text editor, there's a bit called SUBCKT (aka sub-circuit) which is the details of the model.

Comment: This anwser could be improved by putting the text of the comment in the anwser. At the moment this anwser is not self contained and is confusing.

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm necroposting but this is important for anyone in the future reading this: while including ".inc opamp.sub" will work if you're using the generic "opamp" from LTspice, this will NOT work with Opamp2, as OP was using in the image they posted.  Opamp2 requires a user supplied model to function.  If you want a generic opamp to use in your circuit and you require power supply terminals for your simulation, use "UniversalOpAmp".  If you use "UniversalOpAmp" you don't even need the ".inc" statement, it just works out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is add ".inc opamp.sub" command as you did with ".tran 1".
That solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site, but your answer does nothing but repeat YiZhou Wang's answer. Do you have anything else to add relevant to the OP? (also not sure why the upvote).

Comment: Thanks! About your question, 71GA asked for an explanation of the previous answer. Clearly he did not know where to put the command so I answered.

Answer (score 4):

OP amp is the model provided by LTspice. what you should do is just add ". Include opamp.sub" to your simulation cmd.

Comment: How do you do this? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @71GA old comment, but for others wondering the same, just press 's' which brings up the spice directive, or bring it up by clicking on it in the top tool bar. That will prompt a box where you enter the text, e.g. `inc. .lib opamp.sub`,  what you need to type will depend on what you were prompted when you selected the component (e.g. I was prompted in include .lib, not the case with others)

see Nick_Purcell_EE's answer regarding opamp2